# App crashing when using TabView in SwiftUI

Tags: xcode, list, swiftui, xcode11, tabview

When I use a list in my TabView in Xcode 11 project (all in SwiftUI), The app crashes if there is anything other than default Text() in the list when I try to change tabs/views(for example, I​ used a section with a header, and it crashed), followed by this error: 
precondition failure: imported node deleted before its value was read: 118.

I've looked at several posts with similar problems but nothing is useful/ no answers - I've tried calling it from an outside function but that doesn't work either.

section of the code:

```swift
TabView{
     List {
         Text("list item")
         Section(header: Text("Important Tasks")){
               Text("place")
           }
       }

       .tabItem(){ 
           Image(systemName: "house")
           Text("Home")
        }.tag(0)

        CalendarView()
            .tabItem(){
                Image(systemName: "calendar")
                Text("Calendar")
        }.tag(1)
```

Everything displays properly in the first view (HomeView(), the code I showed above) but if i try to switch tabs/views, the app instantly crashes, followed by this error:

precondition failure: imported node deleted before its value was read: 118

Comment: Could you share more of your code please? There is nothing wring in the bit you have included, but maybe it is the CalendarView that causes problems.

Comment: calendar view has nothing right now, just plain Text as a placeholder

Comment: also, if I remove the section bit it works

Comment: Were you able to resolve this issue ?

Comment: @MohamedWasiq I kind of solved the issue; it's just a workaround but heres the post where I answer it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58618470/expande-clickable-area-on-textfield-in-swiftui-xcode-11-2

Comment: Thanks Thomas. But yesterday I updated Xcode from 11.1 to 11.3 and I don't see this crash anymore.