# Expande clickable area on TextField in SwiftUI, Xcode 11.2

Tags: ios, swift, textfield, swiftui

can't figure out how to make clickable area larger to open keyboard on swiftUI (iOS 13, Xcode 11.2). I can only affect visual appearance but not the actual area the user can click on (clickable area == whatever the placeholder text's fontSize is.)

When creating a TextField in swiftUI, it is possible to use frame() to increase size around placeholder text, and I can also use fontsize to make font inside box bigger, but nothing makes clickable area (that brings up keyboard) larger without making font much bigger.

//Code used to modify TextFields

```
struct SignInModifier: ViewModifier {

func body(content: Content) -> some View {
    return content
        .padding(.all).font(.system(size: 18)).border(Color.purple).foregroundColor(Color.purple).shadow(radius: 2).frame(width: 350, height: 50)
    }
}
```

//Where i call the modifier

```
TextField("email address", text: $email).modifier(SignInModifier()).disableAutocorrection(true).keyboardType(.emailAddress)
```

I would like it if when you click on anywhere inside the frame, the keyboard opened up/ you were able to type into the textField. However, I need to click on just the upper part of the placeholder Text in order to type into the TextField

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so I figured a workaround but not exactly a solution; simply embed the TextField in a button and it opens right away no matter where you click

Comment: I can not confirm this behaviour with iOS 14.1

Answer (score 0):

A little work around but works.

```
 struct ContentView: View {
 @State var name = ""
 @State var isFocused = false
  var body: some View {
    ZStack {
        HStack{
            Text(name)
                .font(.system(size: 50 , weight: .black))
                .foregroundColor(isFocused ? Color.clear : Color.black)
            Spacer()
        }
        TextField(name, text: $name , onEditingChanged: { editingChanged in
            isFocused = editingChanged
        }) 
        .font(.system(size: isFocused ? 50 :  100 , weight: .black))
        .foregroundColor(isFocused ? Color.black  : Color.clear)
        .frame(width: 300, height: isFocused ? 50 :  100 , alignment: .center)
                    .padding(.leading, isFocused ? 25 : 0  )
                    .padding(.trailing, isFocused ? 25 : 0 ) 
        .padding(.top,isFocused ? 25 : 0 )

        .padding(.bottom,isFocused ? 25 : 0 )
        
    }.frame(width: 300)
    .background(Color.red.opacity(0.3))
   }
    }
```